# How to mark points in a plot that are over a specified value in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, symbols

Say I have a data set with x values of longitude and Y values of 1 to 100. How can I plot the whole data set and represent all Y values over 90 with a different symbol?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to plot the sets separately, and specify a different symbol for each set i.e.

```
plot(x(Y<=90),Y(Y<=90),'bx',x(Y>90),Y(Y>90),'bo');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do different colors.  The `scatter` function has the ability to specify a **different color for each point** with the syntax [`scatter(x,y,s,c)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html#btrli6o-1_1). For your example, you could do:

```
% make data
rng(0,'twister'); theta = linspace(0,2*pi,150);
x = sin(theta) + 0.75*rand(1,150); x = x*100;
y = cos(theta) + 0.75*rand(1,150); y = y*100;
mask = y>90;

% plot with custom colors for each point
c = zeros(numel(x),3); % matrix of RGB colorspecs
c(mask,:) = repmat([1 0 0],nnz(mask),1); % red
c(~mask,:) = repmat([0 0 1],nnz(~mask),1); % blue
scatter(x,y,10,c,'+');
```

Or instead of and RGB colorspec matrix, you can index into the current colormap.  This allows you to get a nice smooth variation with some value:

```
scatter(x,y,10,y+x,'o') % x+y is mapped to indexes into default colormap, jet(64)
```

You can combine this color mapping with the approach of separating the data into two sets to also get different markers. Split the data, plot the first set with `scatter` as above, `hold on`, and plot the second set with a different marker.  For example,

```
cv = x+y; % or just y, but this is an interesting example
scatter(x(mask),y(mask),10,cv(mask),'+');
hold on
scatter(x(~mask),y(~mask),10,cv(~mask),'o');
```

The result is different marker styles, where `'+'` is used where `y>90` and `'+'` elsewhere, and different colors, where color is determined by mapping the values of `cv=x+y` onto the current colormap.  The idea here is to look at 2 different modes of variations, but you could just use `cv=y`.

[image]